# wordpress gallery plugin won't show gallery online

Tags: wordpress, gallery, nextgen-gallery

i have installed two different gallery plugins (Slideshow Gallery and Nextgen-gallery) i need both of them since they display photos in different ways and i need'em for different pages. I installed previously the "NextGen-gallery" and it works fine. Than i installed the "Slideshow Gallery" but when i put the short code into the page,it doesn't display anything! It's blank! i tried in a different website to leave just "Slideshow gallery" plugin and it did show up.

Is there a problem to install 2 gallery plugins in a website?? What can i do to keep them both??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest posting your question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I had a similar problem with a site of mine and the problem there was NextGenGallery and some other script the main problem was fight between jquery selectors. I ended up using the default gallery of WP and coded the extension for displaying the gallery in a proper way my self. At least like that that I know how things work and is not a biggie change-ing something if needed.